# Simulate 4,000 selects on my CRUD deskto app with JPA

Tags: testing, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, simulate

i have a simple desktop application using JPA with EclipseLink, this application has 7 tables each one with 8 records, everything is ok.

but i want to simulate that my desktop application has like 4000 request of select statements and see if it has a good response is for a school project.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Threads.

Create a class that implements Runnable, in the method run() call you services in a loop. Then create several threads which will run these Runnable.